# JSP pages are not showing all content after kendo UI for JSP was upgraded

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After I upgraded Kendo UI JSP in my Eclipse project, my JSP pages are not showing any content when I run the project.

I used following tag lib: 
`<%@taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>`

I removed this line and after running the project is run, it shows an error for JSP tags. When I add the same line back in, again, none of the content shows.

The previous Kendo UI version is properly displaying all content on the pages with the line I shared, above.

What I do?